# fixing elements whilst scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So, I have a div which I'm trying to keep 100px from the top of the page between to points of the page whilst scrolling. At the moment, my code works-ish but the div is not kept at exactly 100px from the top, instead altering between 0px - 200px

here's what I'm using atm:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var tpxl = $(window).scrollTop();
if( tpxl<100) {
$('#div').css('top',-Math.abs(tpxl)+100 + 'px');
}
else if(tpxl>700) {
$('#div').css('top',-Math.abs(tpxl)+800 + 'px');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Math.abs()` because `tpxl` will always be a positive number. To set the position of the div to be 100px from the current top of the window, use `$(window).scrollTop() + 100 + 'px'`.

I don't really understand why you have the `if` / `else if` structure. The following would keep the div fixed at 100px all the time:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#div').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 100 + 'px');
}).scroll();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G5BVU/

To only set the position "fixed" when the scroll point is less than 100 or more than 700 like for your original code try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var tpxl = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (tpxl < 100 || tpxl > 700) {
        $('#div').css('top', tpxl + 100 + 'px');
    }
}).scroll();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G5BVU/1/

EDIT: To have the element scroll normally except when the window is scrolled between those two points just reverse the `if` condition from my previous example:

```
if (tpxl > 100 && tpxl < 700)
    $('#div').css('top', tpxl + 100 + 'px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5BVU/2/

In all cases provide an initial `top` setting as appropriate.

Comment: I should have explained this better; I need the element to scroll with the rest of the elements until the window scroll distance gets to 100px, I then want the element to stay 100px from the top until the window scroll distance reaches 700px

Comment: See my update and final demo - it may not be quite what you're looking for, but I would hope it gives you enough of an idea to finish it yourself. Whatever you're doing you don't need to negate the value of `tpxl` or use `-Math.abs(tpxl)`.

Comment: This may be an issue with my browser/hardware, but the elements still jitter whilst scrolling

Comment: I tested in Chrome and I only see a tiny bit of jitter depending on how fast I scroll - but remember the element (along with the page) will have moved slightly with every scroll event before your code sets it back to that position so some jitter is inevitable. If you want it to be smooth try using `position:fixed` instead of continously updating the `top` position.